# Merge multiple rows (with same ID) into one?

Tags: sql, teradata

I am looking to merge multiple rows into one row with matching ID's. I am using Teradata SQL.
Example:

```
  SELECT
  id_nbr AS ID,
  contact_type AS contype,
  contact_first_name AS firstName,
  contact_last_name AS lastName,
  contact_phone_number AS phoneNumber,
  contact_address AS address,
  contact_email AS email
  FROM database.account_info
  WHERE (contact_type = 'AAA' OR contact_type = 'BBB' OR contact_type = 'CCC');
```

Result:

```
ID          contype     firstName     lastName    phoneNumber     address        email
111111111   AAA         bob           smith       (999)999-9999   1 Main St      null
111111111   BBB         bob           smith       (888)888-8888   1 random rd    bob@random.com
111111111   CCC         bob           smith       null            null           bob@anotherrandom.com
```

What I want:

```
ID          contypeAAA     firstNameAAA     lastNameAAA    phoneNumberAAA     addressAAA      emailAAA   contypeBBB  firstNameBBB     lastNameBBB    phoneNumberBBB     addressBBB      emailBBB  contypeCCC     firstNameCCC     lastNameCCC    phoneNumberCCC     addressCCC      emailCCC
111111111   AAA            bob              smith          (999)999-9999      1 Main St       null ......etc
```

Is this even possible? This would help me tremendously..! Thanks in advance!

Editing this, contype for ID does not always have all 3 contypes. This makes it trickier. Example, ID: 99999999 can have contype: 'AAA','BBB' only but should return null values for all 'CCC' values since it does not exist.

Comment: The easiest way is two self-joins. Are there always rows for each contact type or is there a contact type which always exists?

Comment: There is NOT always a contact type for each ID but can be up to three different(AAA,BBB,CCC).

Comment: Are there only 3 total potential values (for the entire table), and each id will have up to three of those?

Comment: No there are 8 but i need these 3 (if it exists per ID).

Comment: use the pivot, that should do it

Comment: @access_granted Thanks for the info.

Comment: @dnoeth Thanks for the info. I will do some digging on this.

Comment: @access_granted I thought `pivot` was an advanced `group by` that needed an aggregated function. Not sure how to make that work.

Comment: @Scratte, it was introduced in (I think) TD 15.10 as a language construct, similar to Oracle. Before that you could hack around using case max() expressions. There should be examples here on S/Oflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this will work (I tested it on an Oracle 11g, not a Teradata):

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT id_nbr AS ID,
               contact_type AS contype,
               contact_first_name AS firstName,
               contact_last_name AS lastName,
               contact_phone_number AS phoneNumber,
               contact_address AS address,
               contact_email AS email
          FROM database.account_info
         WHERE contact_type in ('AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC')
        )
 PIVOT (max(firstName) AS firstName,
        max(lastName) AS lastName,
        max(phoneNumber) AS phone,
        max(email) AS email,
        max(address) AS address
   FOR contype IN ('AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC')
        )
```

The last line may require an alias, one of:

```
        ) AS derived_pivot
        ) derived_pivot
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer :) testing this later when I can!

Comment: @JCP Once you've tested the SQL please accept my answer. Unless it doesn't work, of course.

Comment: You just need to add *aliases*, Oracle supports omitting them, Standard/Teradata SQL doesn't: `)
        ) as dt`

Comment: @dnoeth Do you mean at the very end? If I put a `CCC') ) AS dt`, I get an error in Oracle, unless I omit `AS`, so only `CCC') ) dt` works

Comment: Oracle chokes on Standard SQL's `AS`, but not for column aliases, only Larry knows, why :-)

Comment: @dnoeth Btw: Thank you for checking by answer. It's appreciated.

Comment: @Scratte Thanks! Ultimately your solution helped me solve my issue. Thank you very much for your time :)